# Python3 - np.histogram output decimal issue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, histogram

I am new to python, I have got list which has a lot of number, then I would like to use np.histogram & pandas to generate a histogram like csv file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins=5)
print(counts)
print(bin_edges)
```

And I get the following output:

```
[27 97 24 27 11]
[-19.12   -8.406   2.308  13.022  23.736  34.45 ]
```

Then I tried to write the data into CSV file

```
bin = 5
min = np.delete(bin_edges, bin)
max = np.delete(bin_edges, 0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Min': min, 'Max': max, 'Count': counts})
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
```

However, I have got the following file ...

```
Min Max Count
-19.12  -8.405999999999999  27
-8.405999999999999  2.3080000000000034  97
2.3080000000000034  13.02200000000001   24
13.02200000000001   23.736000000000008  27
23.736000000000008  34.45   11
```

Is there any way that I can restrict the decimal numbers?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `float_format` parameter of the `to_csv()` function.

```
df.to_csv(
  'data.csv',
  index=False,
  sep='\t',
  float_format='%.3f')
```

In the example above the output is to 3 decimal places. See the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Mullinscr. But how to keep the "bin gap" identical when I write to the csv file?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about 'bin gap'?